# .mousemove on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, mousemove

What is wrong with .mousemove because wont to do noting on IE8. Must expand the disabled inputs with value > 20 characters. Only on IE8 is not working.
And another thing, why isn't dragging back after cursor is on other element.

```
$('input[disabled]').mousemove(function(){
      if ($(this).val().length > 20) {
       $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
       $(this).animate({width: 300}, 'slow');
      }
});
```

Check the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/183/

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should be using the readonly attribute instead as this will allow further interaction with the input box.

your css

```
    input{
        margin:10px;
    }
    input.readonly {
        color: grey;
        cursor:default
    }
```

and your form

```
<form action="form_action.asp" method="get">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Foghorn Leghorn Foghorn Leghorn" readonly="true" class="readonly" /><br />
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="" readonly="true" class="readonly" /><br />
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Foghorn Leghorn" readonly="true" class="readonly" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form" style=""/>
</form>
```

and your jQuery

```
    $('input[readonly]').mousemove(function(){
       if ($(this).val().length > 20) {
                $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
                $(this).animate({width: 300}, 'slow');
                $(this).parent().addClass('cooling');
              }
    });
```

Comment: yes it works, and it's possible to run back on the original width when my cursor leave that input? Thank you.